# Update child component in JSF (AJAX)

Tags: ajax, jsf

I want update subcomponent with id="two". Everything is working until i put form in another component like h:panelGrid.

```
<h:panelGroup id="one">
    <h:panelGroup id="two">
        <h:outputText value="#{testBean.num}"/>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>

<br/>

<h:panelGrid columns="1">
    <h:form>
        <p:commandButton value="update" 
                         action="#{testBean.inc()}"
                         update=":one:two"
                         ajax="true"
                         />
    </h:form>
</h:panelGrid>
```

In this case i am getting:
SF1073: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException caught during processing of RENDER_RESPONSE 6 : UIComponent-ClientId=, Message=one

What is wrong ?

PS: update=":one" is works, but i dont want update whole "one" component.
[image: error stacktrace]

Here is a full code.

xhtml page:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:panelGroup id="one">
            <h:panelGroup id="two">
                <h:outputText value="#{testBean.num}"/>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:panelGroup>

        <br/>

        <h:panelGrid columns="1" id="table">
            <h:form id="form">
                <p:commandButton value="update" 
                                 action="#{testBean.inc()}"
                                 update=":one:two"
                                 ajax="true"
                                 />
            </h:form>
            <!-- .....another components .... -->
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

the bean:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable{
    private int num;

    public void inc() {
        System.out.println("inc");
        num++;
    }

    public int getNum() {
        return num;
    }

    public void setNum(int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a parent component of `one` ? if so them you need to specify all parent tree .

Comment: @Mifmif, no, only this code in html body.

Comment: Post the complete code of your JSF page to replicate the problem.

Comment: @Vovan this is unrelated to Java and Java-EE

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza, posted code on pastebin

Comment: Do not post it there. Post it here.

Comment: From your given code, there should be no problems, unless you're doing something else you haven't posted here.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza, running exactly this code
http://piccy.info/view3/6500941/94a9ef18c10ec5b41f526b625ad7942c/orig/

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza my wild guess is that's it's actually trying to use `:one` as a naming container prefix to look up `two` and failing at this point.

Comment: Which JSF version you're using?

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza, Mojarra 2.2.5 on GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This very unhelpful error is caused by your invalid `update` syntax: `:one:two` first tries to look up `one` as a `NamingContainer` (see [Communications in JSF 2.0](http://balusc.blogspot.de/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#AjaxRenderingOfContentOutsideForm)). If it finds the component, but it isn't a `NamingContainer`, it throws the exception you're seeing.

To fix this, simply specify the correct update value:

```
<p:commandButton value="update" action="#{testBean.inc()}"
  update=":two" ajax="true" />
```

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Me too, actually. It wasn't until I had a look at the source that it dawned on me.